# Twitter Typeahead min length = 0 equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead.js

I'm using [Twitter's Typeahead.js (Not the one included in Bootstrap)](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and I was wondering if there was a similar function to minLength=0 that exists in [Better-Typeahead (Bootstrap)](https://github.com/ptnplanet/Bootstrap-Better-Typeahead)

[Triggering on input looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115059/programmatically-triggering-typeahead-js-result-display), but I don't want there to be any text in the input box when the dropdown is triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, Datasets have a `minLength` option, see the code [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/v0.9.3/src/dataset.js#L28). It's been around [since v0.9.1](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#091-april-1-2013), but it hasn't made its way to the README yet.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength: 3,
  local: [/* ... */]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've temporarily switched from using Twitter Typeahead for the sake of productivity, but I'll try this in the future

Comment: I have it set like this:


$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        minLength: 3,
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: geoLocation.ttAdapter()
    });

But still makes request at the first typing