# `display` option in typeahead.js does not work

Tags: mongoose, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have been at this for hours, and I am sure I am making a dumb mistake. But I am at a loss...

**Here is what I have checked:**

**docs:**

- https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#usage
- https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options

**Stackoverflow:**

- [typeahead.js doesn't display the dropdown using remote data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757076/typeahead-js-doesnt-display-the-dropdown-using-remote-data)
- [Typeahead.js / Bloodhound display just one result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370496/typeahead-js-bloodhound-display-just-one-result)
- [typeahead.js - Displaying all Prefetched Datums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768401/typeahead-js-displaying-all-prefetched-datums)

**Examples/ google / etc**
...

Here is my setup. I have a mongoDB which I have created an API search path for with mongoose / Node.js. I have verified that the search API works correctly.

**HTML (pug)**

```
.answer-container
    form(method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")#answer-form.form
            label(for="new-answer") Answer:
            input(required minlength="1" maxlength="80" type="text" name="new-answer" id="new-answer" placeholder="Answer Text" autocomplete="off").new-answer-input
            br
            input(type="submit" name="submit" disabled autocomplete="off" value="Submit")#answer-submit-button
    .answer-messages
```

*I have verified that the pug template is working as expected.*

**JS (typeahead and bloodhound)**

```
    var answer_suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("text"),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote:{
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/answers/search?text=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
      });

      $('#new-answer').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        autoselect: true,
        minLength: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'answers',
        source: answer_suggestions,
        display: 'text',
        limit: 10
      });
```

**PROBLEM**
If I remove the `display` option, I can SEE the results are coming in from the API and everything is working. If I include it, I get no results.

RESULTS
[Raw results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twIry.png)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "64401c91bc76fdfca320c118",
    "text": "pneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "64403bb708645fb7abbe2db3",
    "text": "pneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "64403bdf08645fb7abbe2dbf",
    "text": "hemopneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I have tried refactoring the data as a json object, I have tried using a function in `display` but nothing seems to work.

All I want is the results list to simply show the answer text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my question to exclude extraneous info and I will provide my answer below.

The issue was that when I was seeing or logging my data in the `typeahead` `display` function or on the page itself it was showing me the NESTED data. Confused? so was I...

Here is what I thought my API was returning to `bloodhound`

```
[
  {
    "_id": "64401c91bc76fdfca320c118",
    "text": "pneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "64403bb708645fb7abbe2db3",
    "text": "pneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "64403bdf08645fb7abbe2dbf",
    "text": "hemopneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Here is what is was ACTUALLY returning.

```
{ 
answers:{
[
  {
    "_id": "64401c91bc76fdfca320c118",
    "text": "pneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "64403bb708645fb7abbe2db3",
    "text": "pneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "64403bdf08645fb7abbe2dbf",
    "text": "hemopneumothorax",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
}
```

I found this by logging the data in the `bloodhound` optional `transform` function. This extra object was my culprit. Since bloodhound stripped it before it got to typeahead, I never saw it.

**HERE is the working code:**

```
    var answer_suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('text'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote:{
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/answers/search?text=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            transform: (response) => {
                return $.map(response.answers, function(object) {
                  return { text: object.text };
                });
              }
        }
      });

      $('#new-answer').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        autoselect: true,
        minLength: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'typeahead-answers',
        source: answer_suggestions,
        display: 'text',
        templates: {
            notFound: '<div>Not Found</div>',
            pending: '<div>Loading...</div>',
            suggestion:  function(data) {
                return `<div>${data.text}</div>`
            },
        },
        limit: 10
      });
```

You can see I added a custom `transform` in `bloodhound`. I also added a custom template in `typeahead` but this was not required.

I hope this helps someone. Not enough docs or examples, IMO.

Data logging is your friend.