# Keep Twitter Typeahead suggestion dropdown open

Tags: javascript, twitter, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

At the moment I cannot design the typeahead template I have with Google chrome Dev tools because when ever i open it as it's stated in Twitter Docs

```
#Input Control Loses Focus#

deactivate typeahead
close dropdown menu
remove hint
clear suggestions from dropdown menu
```

I do not need this behaviour. I want the dropdown to disappear only when the user click something else on the body,

Any help really appreciated

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: @NullHead, I think I edited the source code file at the time, man this is an old question.. sorry not sure what exactly i did

Comment: Have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790265/8494462

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
.on('blur', function(){
  ev = $.Event("keydown");
  ev.keyCode = ev.which = 40;
  $('.typeahead').trigger(ev);
  return true;
});
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/17/)** (start typing t in the demo)

Here is the [reference](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/798#issuecomment-39098474)

Comment: .on('blur', function(){  
 $('#myinput .typeahead').typeahead('open');
});