# How do I trigger an onSelect event in for an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.0.3 to autocomplete an text input. I'm also using gravity form's Dynamic Population to add a value to the autocomplete text input. How can I trigger the autocomplete to look up data related to the dynamically populated value?

I've tried to add simple jQuery trigger functions, with no luck.

Here is a snippit of my autocomplete (typeahead) initialization:

```
$('.restaurant_name input').typeahead({
  source: function(typeahead, query) {
    var _this = this;
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/restaurants.json?q=" + query,
      success: function(data) { 
        return typeahead.process(data);
      }
    });
  }, onselect: function (obj) {
    if (obj.City != ''){
      $(".restaurant_city input").attr("value", obj.City);      
    }
    if (obj.State != ''){
      $(".hotel_state input").attr("value", obj.State);     
    }
    if (obj.Zip != ''){
      $(".hotel_zip input").attr("value", obj.Zip);     
    }
  },
  property: "LocationName1"
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115059/programmatically-triggering-typeahead-js-result-display).

I just had to add:

```
$(".hotel_name input").typeahead('lookup').focus();
```

Comment: Anyone who uses the solution above: Remember that it has to go after the typeahead input function.