# How TypeAhead engine have been called?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

When i am writing something in the editor, then the typeAhead engine is calling perfectly but when i am directly appending something into editor than typeahead engine is not calling. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically triggering typeahead.js result display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115059/programmatically-triggering-typeahead-js-result-display)

Comment: I am able to trigger the typeahead code but not able to trigger the typeahead search engine. For eg i have built the search engine in typeahead and i have sent the query and triggered with method described in that link but the saecrh engine is not triggering

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you expect and what does happen? Worth to provide some code samples.